# How do you load .js files with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
<%@ Page Language="VB"  %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <script runat="server">

Sub Page_Load(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("basicjs", "basic.js")
End Sub

</script>
    <title>RegisterClientScriptBlock Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<form runat="server">
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="clickme" onclick="click()"/>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using ASP.net (just learning) with VB. I can't seem to get Javascript code to work with ASP VB code. My main problem seems to be that .js files are not loading. In the example, basic.js just contains a function `click()` that calls an `alert()` message. How do I get .js files to load with ASP code?

Comment: Check the source html of the downloaded page to check to see if the expected script include has been generated, e.g. `<script type="text/JavaScript" src="basic.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes, that is missing when I view the source. Pretty much everything is included except everything inside the script tags. How can I make sure it doesn't ignore or skip over it?

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint in your `Page_Load` method to see if it is being correctly fired?  Also I'm assuming that you are aware that you can just write the `script` tag manually in your .aspx?

Comment: If the tag is not being rendered try updating yout Page_Load Event as I've updated in my answer, to:Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any server-side code to load a JavaScript file.  Just put this in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="basic.js"></script>
```

Comment: ASP.Net has mecahnisms for managing and generating these includes in code behind / server side logic which I'm pretty sure is what the poster wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a client-side script language. It's not something your server should execute; the client should.

ASP is a server-side language that generates some output that's presented to the user. Therefore, it cannot be ASP's responsibility to execute a JavaScript.

Instead, you should just include the JavaScript in your HTML, thus telling the client to execute it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="basic.js"></script>
```

Comment: Although technically correct I'm pretty sure that the poster is already aware of this - ASP.Net has mecahnisms for managing and generating these includes in code behind / server side logic which I'm pretty sure is what the poster wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the include tag is being rendered to the page by viewing the page source from the browser. Once you've established the include tag exists check the path to the script file.

[This article explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx145dw2.aspx) how to resolve the path correctly

Basically use this in your onload event:

```
Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("basicjs", ResolveClientUrl("~/basic.js"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like...

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("JScripts", ResolveUrl("~/JSFolderName/basic.js"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the basic.js is accessible from the page? I mean if the page and js file located under one folder?

You can get more idea from here:

http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-01-19/asp_net-add-script-tags-include-javascript-master-pages-head-tag

Thanks!

Dhananjay

Answer (score 0):

You need to include as follow

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  // your code goes here.
</script>
```

if javascript is in file then follow

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript_file_path"> 
      // your code goes here.
    </script>
```

Comment: Although technically correct I don't think that this is what the poster is trying to achieve - ASP.Net has mecahnisms for managing and generating these includes in code behind / server side logic which I'm pretty sure is what the poster wants to do.